# Regular expression not returning propper matches

Tags: php, regex, string

I am currently experiencing some problems with my regular expression on my PHP server.

This is my current regulair expression:

```
/\{content="(?:([^"\|]*)\|?)+"\}/
```

And I want it to match:

```
{content="default|test|content|text"}
```

And then return this in the matches:

```
default
test
content
text
```

But when I currently execute it I get back this in my matches:

```
array (
  0 => '{content="default|test|content|text"}',
  1 => '',
)
```

Do any of you have a problem what I am doing wrong?

With kind regards,

Youri Arktesteijn

Comment: Define "I currently execute" please. How do you execute, which function are you using etc.

Comment: preg_match('/\{content="(?:([^"\|]*)\|?)+"\}/', $sContent, $aMatches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can use positive lookaheads and positive lookbehinds.

Three phases:

1. We match the beginning quote, but don't catch it in our output. Then we match anything that's not a pipe. Then we match a pipe without catching it.
2. Non-pipes between pipes
3. Non-pipes and non-quotes between a pipe and a quote.

Here's the code.

```
<?php

$string = '{content="default|test|content|text"}';
$my_matches = preg_match_all('!((?<=")([^|]+)(?=[|])|(?<=[|])([^|]+)(?=[|])|(?<=[|])([^|"]+)(?="))!',$string,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);

?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
[0] => default
[1] => test
[2] => content
[3] => text
)
```

Once you have the logic working, then you can pair the look ahead and look behind characters to shorten the match string.

```
$my_matches = preg_match_all('!(?<=["|])([^|"]+)(?=[|"])!',$string,$matches);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
[0] => default
[1] => test
[2] => content
[3] => text
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it is possible by using a single line of regular expression. Anyway try the following code,

```
<?php
if (preg_match('/\{content="(?:([^\"]+))"\}/', $sContent, $matches) > 0) {
    $result = explode('|', $matches[1]);
} else {
    $result = array();
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r($result, true) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Jup, as much as I hate it, I think that is the only solution.